# Add column for percentages

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a df who looks like this:

```
    Total  Initial  Follow   Sched   Supp  Any
0    5525   3663     968      296     65   533
```

I transpose the df 'cause I have to add a column with the percentages based on column 'Total'
Now my df looks like this:

```
        0      
Total    5525
Initial  3663
Follow   968
Sched    296
Supp     65
Any      533
```

So, How can I add this percentage column?
The expected output looks like this

```
        0       Percentage
Total    5525     100
Initial  3663     66.3
Follow   968      17.5
Sched    296      5.4
Supp     65       1.2 
Any      533      9.6
```

Do you know how can I add this new column?
I'm working in jupyterlab with pandas and numpy

Answer (score 1):

Multiple column `0` by scalar from `Total` with [`Series.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html), then multiple by `100` by [`Series.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mul.html) and last round by [`Series.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.round.html):

```
df['Percentage'] = df[0].div(df.loc['Total', 0]).mul(100).round(1)
print (df)
            0  Percentage
Total    5525       100.0
Initial  3663        66.3
Follow    968        17.5
Sched     296         5.4
Supp       65         1.2
Any       533         9.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below df:

```
In [1328]: df
Out[1328]: 
            b
a            
Total    5525
Initial  3663
Follow    968
Sched     296
Supp       65
Any       533


In [1327]: df['Perc'] = round(df.b.div(df.loc['Total', 'b']) * 100, 1)
In [1330]: df
Out[1330]: 
              b   Perc
a                   
Total    5525  100.0
Initial  3663   66.3
Follow    968   17.5
Sched     296    5.4
Supp       65    1.2
Any       533    9.6
```